# Linearlayout with static size inside scrollview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-scrollview

I'm developing and android project which i need to have a linearlayout with static sizes. but the height of my linearlayout is more than screen size (2000dp) so i put it in a ScrollView.

The problem is its height is not static and it's equal screen height.

How can solve this?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2000dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="8" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:background="#880000" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:background="#008800" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#000088" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Output:

[image]

thanks in advance

Comment: If you the height the of parent view, then why dont you give divided height like android:layout_height="665dp"

Comment: hmm! because i will change this 2000 in future depends of screen sizes (mobile/tablet)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try changing the height of ScrollView to wrap content

```
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Comment: can you try giving the  android:layout_height="2000dp" to scrollview

Answer (score 0):

`ScrollView` calculate the height of its child regardless of the child's `layout_height`. You can see the [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/widget/ScrollView.java#1235) of `measureChild` and `measureChildWithMargins`. They are responsible for the calculation of child dimensions. Inside `ScrollView` they perform computations using `MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED` for the child height.

So the only way to do what you're asking for is simply wrap your `LinearLayout` in a `FrameLayout`:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2000dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <!-- items here -->

        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</ScrollView>
```